# Circle image button take onClick event (when touch outside its image) which should be received by nearby button

Tags: android, user-interface, imagebutton

I want to make a group view that contain 3 image button that when I click on a circle, that circle will become bigger while other become smaller.
[image: 1][image: 2] [image: 3]
The problem is when I click smaller button, the biggest button take the click event instead. 
For example, in this cased, top button will receive click event.
[image: 4] 
  If I want the middle button, I must click a little farther from big button, it maybe outside the circle of middle button like in the screenshot below. 
[image: 5]
This is layout xml of the groupview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/blue100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mid_circle"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/green100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_circle"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/red100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bot_circle"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The source code can be download [here] (https://github.com/ttpro1995/Android_ThreeCircleViewGroup/releases/tag/0.1)
I want that when I click on smaller button, the smaller button should receive the click event, not the big one. Please help me fix.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because bottom image cover middle image [image: Problem Screen]

now the solution is you need to change circlegroupview framlayout layout width 200dp to 250dp or as per your need. [image: after changing width 200dp to 250dp]

I think We can not convert rectangle to circle but instead of this you can crop the images, remove the space surrounded with image, so the minimum area covered.

Comment: Thank you for help.<r>
I aware that the image button is rectangle, which cover nearby button.<r>
But what I really want is make the Image Button that fit really with drawable (which is round, not rectangle).
I don't want to extend frame layout because I want big button overlap small button.